# How to send dictionary json object to params in android

Tags: android, json, dictionary

I dont know how to send the dictionary json data to this facebookData params.I have posted the relevant code below. please check that:

**Params:**

```
 params.put("email", "exampleEmail@gmail.com" );

params.put("facebookData", facebookData );  -->I need to pass the dictionary json object to this facebookData
```

**Dictionary JsonData:**

```
{
  "email":"exampleEmail@gmail.com",

"facebookData":{
      "about" : "duration",
    "access_token":"aklfnlanfklmskladfnmklankflnklafnklanklsfklk",
    "age":28,
    "birthday":"563221800",
    "email":"myexampleemail@gmail.com",
    "facebook_user_id":"561394210664929",
    "first_name":"Bradley",
    "gender":"male",
    "id":"561394210664929",
    "is_show_only":"Men and Women",
    "latitude":"13.05505200",
    "longitude":"80.23623600",
    "name":"Bradley Cummings",
    "profilePicture":"some picture for eg",
    "provider":"Facebook"
}
}
```

So far I tried like,directly setting that value in string to that params.But it is not working for me.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank You.

Comment: put `facebookData.toString();`

Comment: @PratikButani how to do all the string value in jsonobject ? then only i can do that facebookData.toString(); any suggestion or sample post related to this?

Comment: You can create `JSONObject` and put all string in that.

Comment: @PratikButani ok I will try that one and tell you.